# Field must be an accumulator object error when trying to group by object as key

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to type-safe group documents by multiple properties from a collection. I figured out that the problem is not the grouping by multiple properties itself but that the key is an object (`new { }`) instead of a string.

This works:

```
collection.Aggregate().Group(x => x.Name, x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Sum(s => 1) }).ToList();
```

This does not work:

```
collection.Aggregate().Group(x => new { Name = x.Name }, x => new { Name = x.Key.Name, Count = x.Sum(s => 1) }).ToList();
```

The Error is:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: The field 'Name' must be an accumulator object.'

When I convert the query that doesn't work to a string I get the following:

```
aggregate([{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "Name" : "$Name" }, "Name" : "$_id.Name", "Count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }])
```

I guess the problem here is this part `"Name" : "$_id.Name"`. How do I fix this problem?

I'm currently using version 2.8.0 of the mongodb driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the driver behaves correctly here but what you're experiencing is the limitation of [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage in Aggregation Framework. The documentation states that:

> The output documents contain an _id field which contains the distinct group by key. The output documents can also contain computed fields that hold the values of some **accumulator** expression grouped by the $group’s _id field

So in your case you're trying to refer to `_id` field without any accumulator.

From the logical perspective your queries appear to be similar. First one gets translated into:

```
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$Name",
        "Count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Second one would return the same data but you have an object as a grouping key. To fix that in C# you need to introduce `.First()` expression which will be translated into [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html), so running:

```
Col.Aggregate()
    .Group(
        x => new { Name = x.Name }, 
        x => new { Name = x.First().Name, Count = x.Sum(s => 1) })
    .ToList();
```

will run below query on the database:

```
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "Name" : "$Name"
        },
        "Name" : {
            "$first" : "$Name"
        },
        "Count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

It works but **logically** it returns the same data as first aggregation